# EditText input type displays different keyboards

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-edittext

I am using the same EditText for all smartphones. All of them are api 26+.

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:digits="0123456789,"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:letterSpacing="0.2"
            android:maxLength="9"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:textSize="@dimen/default_text"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

But in some smart-phones keyboard displays in different way. In EditText I allow user to write [0123456789,] symbols. But as you can see in one of keyboard I am not allowed to enter commas. How to have 1 type of keyboard for all of devices? Whats the reason of that they display differently if I specified inputType?

[image: keyboard1]
[image: keyboard2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different Android phone manufacture customize android OS as per their need, keyboard layout can be modified to appear differently. Even you can have apps which can provide different keyboard UI. If you mentioned *android:inputType="number"* and even if keyboard layout displays dot(.) or Comma(,) it won't accept the same. Why would you accept comma(,) for field which accepts only number? If you want decimal number then use *android:inputType="numberDecimal"*. If you want common layout across all smartphones then you can create your own keyboard layout & inflate it, I won't suggest until you have specific requirement that needs to cover from security point of view like password/PIN entering fields.

Comment: Your answer seems to be correct. But numberDecimal does not allow to put comma. I can put only dot there instead

Comment: @CallMePedro numberDecimal will allow only numbers & dot(.) to allow floating numbers like amount field etc.

Comment: Input type number should only accept digits from 0-9 but if you specify argument android:digits and add there a comma or dot then input type number will also accept comma and dot in editText

Comment: In one smartphone it accepted in other no. So probably I will allow user to write strings and display for them numeric keyboard

Comment: Yes, you can accept only numbers with decimal through numeric keyboard. Once focus moves out of current edittext you can display in specific format you want including comma.